# Better way to achieve 100% div height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a better way to achieve 100% height with auto scroll as shown in the plnkr below without having to have all those fill classes added? I feel like there must be a more elegant way.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dh63n6j9R6t9LiBKhHQA?p=preview

```
<section class="content fill">
    <div class="container-fluid fill">
        <div class="row fill">
            <div class="col-sm-12 fill">
                <div class="row fill">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 fill">
                        <div class="main-container-wrapper">
                            <h1>Main</h1>
                            <div class="inner">Overflow</div>
                            <div class="inner">Overflow</div>
                            <div class="inner">Overflow</div>
                            <div class="inner">Overflow</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="right-container-wrapper">
                            <h1>Right</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and my css

/* Styles go here */

```
body, html{
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-container-wrapper{
  background: red;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.right-container-wrapper{
  background: orange;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.fill{
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner{
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
```

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/dd1awq12/2/

Comment: for code integrity. Do you mind adding your changes to the original plnkr in a fork? thanks

Comment: This question looks like it might be a pretty good fit for [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), provided that (a) you want _every aspect_ of your code reviewed, not just some, (b) your code is _already working_, and (c) you're asking for a review of _concrete, real code_, not abstract design (whether or not it's expressed as code). If you agree with all of those, please read about [what's on topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and, if your question fits that, delete it here and repost it on CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use viewport height: `100vh`.

Answer (score 1):

Viewport height and its counterpart viewport width will resize your container based on the browser window. You would write the code like this:

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

100 is 100% of the height of the window (or width, respectively).